# Como enviar un parametro en una consulta LIKE

Tags: html, mysql, sql, asp.net

Muy bien mi problema es que estoy haciendo un formulario, y tengo un txt que se encarga de buscar, pero hasta tengo que poner los datos manuales en la consulta para que funcione, y lo que quiero es que tome el valor del txt para buscar a partir de ahií: les dejo el codigo de manera resumida
Vista

```
<td>
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txt_clasif" runat="server"   ReadOnly="false"   Text=""></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Consulta:

```
Dim buscarclasif As String = txt_clasif.Text

sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " and tc.nombre_clasif  like '%%'"
```

Dentro de los porcientos pongo mis valores pero no se como poner lo que va en mi caja de texto de busqueda:

```
dbComm = New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConn)
dbComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?nombre_clasif", buscarclasif)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tu query es un string que no recibe parámetros propiamente tal, los parámetros los usas cuando utilizas un procedimiento almacenado, en este caso debes concatenar el valor del textbox con tu query.

```
sqlQuery = sqlQuery & " and tc.nombre_clasif  like '%" & buscarclasif & "%'"
```

Adicional a esta implementación de ejemplo... debes preocuparte en esta y todas tus querys que realices prevenir la inyección sql (cadenas que puedan modificar tu consulta principal y ejecuten código que no corresponde al comportamiento que debe tener la aplicación).

Comment: -1, esto es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. De hecho, lo recomendable es utilizar parámetros.

Comment: @jachguate la inyección SQL es objeto de otra consulta o recomendación para que investigue, pero la respuesta resuelve el problema. Y utilizar parámetros por sí solos no previene la inyección SQL.

Comment: 1. No hay nada que impida el uso de una consulta parametrizada en un `select` cualquiera, sin el uso de procedimientos almacenados. 2. Si bien es cierto que tu respuesta ahora menciona el tema de la inyección, en gran parte el _origen del problema_ está en concatenar el valor introducido por el usuario. Si bien la consulta parametrizada no es la única medida a tomar para prevenir ser vulnerable, es una de las más importantes y dejar eso por fuera de una respuesta, en mi opinión, hace que la respuesta sea de baja calidad, aunque resuelva el problema del OP. Un saludo.

Comment: No me ha funcionado supongo que el "buscarclasif" no me trae nada, hay alguna manera de verificar si lleva los datos esa variable?

Comment: Colocando un punto de interrupción en tu código pero para determinar dónde tendrías que colocar parte del código completo, no se sabe si es un autocomplete o quien ejecuta la accion de buscar es un botón con un postback, o ajax, la información y el código de tu pregunta inicial es insuficiente para dar una respuesta